# verilog, binary length of a parameter

Tags: verilog

My module gets a parameter and I want to have a counter in my code to that value. say for example, `parameter n=16` and I want to define `reg [x:0] i` so I can count to n. how can I find x ? there should be a real easy way ?

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of options, depending on what your tools support.

- Write your own `log2` function
- Use `$clog2`

There is a lengthy discussion of this here: http://www.rhinocerus.net/forum/lang-verilog/646074-how-get-bit-width-value-verilog-compile-time.html

Comment: You could then instantiate `reg [$clog(n)-1:0] i` or `integer i_w = $clog(n); reg [i_w-1:0] i`

Answer (score 2):

you must use generate statement 
here are some samples
http://www.rhinocerus.net/forum/lang-verilog/431130-using-generate-statement-verilog.html